# 'key' is declared but its value is never read when set google chrome extension v3 local storage value

Tags: typescript

I define a function with typescript like this:

```
setLocalStorage: async (key: string, value: string): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.set({
        key: value
      }, function () {
        resolve("");
      });
    });
  },
```

but the Visual Studio Code shows error:

```
'key' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
```

the key was obviously used in the chrome storage set function, why did this happen? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `key` value not the "key" as property name, you should modify the code like this(*note the square brackets*):

```js
setLocalStorage: async (key: string, value: string): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.set({
        [key]: value
      }, function () {
        resolve("");
      });
    });
  },
```